# How to remove the default selection checkboxes in ng-grid?

Tags: ng-grid

By default multiselection is enabled and ng-grid displays checkboxes on the left side. How to keep multiselection but get rid of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Set  `enableRowHeaderSelection` to `false`.

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {
    ...
     enableRowHeaderSelection: false
    ...
    };
```